# Python class behavior to different type global arguments

Tags: python-3.x

Why class Test change global k (list) but l(int) is not changed?

```
k = [20]
l = 10

class Test:
    def __init__(self, x, l):
        self.x = x
        self.l = l

    def vb(self):
        self.x[0] = 0
        self.l = 0

obj = Test(k, l)
print(obj.x, obj.l)
obj.vb()
print(k, l)
```

#### [20] 10

#### [0] 10

Comment: Lists are mutable -- if you change their contents it affects all references to them. Ints and floats are not, you *can't* change what's at their memory location (easily, at least).

Comment: You assigned a new value to `l`; there is no further reference to the original int.  But you *didn't* assign a new value to `x`, you modified the existing list.